# Matplotlib - dynamic plot height, horizontal bars always 1px height

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm dynamically generating a horizontal bar plot using MatPlotLib. It works pretty well most of the time, until people try to plot a very large numbers of data points. MatPlotLib tries to squish all of the bars into the plot and they start to disappear.

The ideal solution would be to generate the plot so that every horizontal bar is one pixel in height, with 1px separating every bar. The total height of the resulting plot image would then be dependent on the number of bars. But as everything in MatPlotLib is relative, I'm getting really stuck in how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show some code please, along with an illustration of the issue.

Comment: You can specify the figure size in inches, which relate to pixels by the dpi. If you stretch the axes to span the entire figure, you should be able to calculate pixel-precise positions.

Comment: Apologies, current code is [here](https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/blob/c81d34c8c287950dbdfe178dab60fd355d7a63a5/multiqc/plots/bargraph.py#L330-L383). Need to run now, but will try to make a working minimal example tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows how you can plot lines with 1 pixel width:

```
yinch = 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,yinch), facecolor='w')
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)

ypixels = int(yinch*fig.get_dpi())

for i in range(ypixels):
    
    if i % 2 == 0:
        c = 'k'
    else:
        c = 'w'
    
    ax.plot([0,np.random.rand()], [i,i], color=c, linewidth=72./fig.get_dpi())

ax.set_ylim(0,ypixels)
ax.axis('off')
```

This is what the result looks like (magnified 200%):

[image]

### edit:

Using a different dpi is not problem, but then using `plot()` becomes less useful because you cant specify the linewidth units. You can calculate the needed linewidth, but i think using `barh()` is more clear in that scenario.

In the example above i simply disabled the axis to focus on the 1px bars, if you remove that you can plot as normal. Spacing around it is not a problem because Matplotlib isn't bound to the 0-1 range for a Figure, but you want to add `bbox_inches='tight'` to your savefig to include artists outside of the normal 0-1 range. If you spend a lot of time 'precise' plotting within you axes, i think its easier to stretch the axis to span the entire figure size. You of course take a different approach but that would require you to also calculate the axes size in inches. Both angles would work, it depends or your precise case which might be more convenient.

Also be aware that old versions of Matplotlib (<2.0?) have a different default `figure.dpi` and `savefig.dpi`. You can avoid this by adding `dpi=fig.get_dpi()` to your `savefig` statement. One of many reasons to upgrade. ;)

```
yinch = 2
dpi = 128

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,yinch), facecolor='w', dpi=dpi)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)

ypixels = int(yinch*fig.get_dpi())

for i in range(ypixels):
    
    if i % 2 == 0:
        c = '#aa0000'
    else:
        c = 'w'
    ax.barh(i,np.random.rand(), height=1, color=c)

ax.set_title('DPI %i' % dpi)
ax.set_ylim(0,ypixels)

fig.savefig('mypic.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks for this! Is it possible to do this with spacing around the plot area? I have axes and a plot title, legend etc.

Comment: I think one should mention that this works if and only if dpi is set to 72. And it actually relies on setting the spacing around the plot to 0 in y-direction, which is far from desireable.

Comment: @tallphil, sure no problem, see my updated answer. Adding `bbox_inches='tight'` will take care of  getting all plotted `artists` within the resulting figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it works with every dpi, but when using `plot()` you would have to specify the appropriate linewidth like `linewidth=72/dpi`.

Comment: +1 for the `bbox_inches='tight'` hook. This is what makes this solution actually useful. You could highlight this in the text. Also adding `linewidth=72./fig.get_dpi()` to the first approach would actually make is useful. Do you by chance have any idea why the ticklabels are off by one bar (which is also the case in [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42541438/4124317))?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you need to account for the last 'blank' bar, since you initialize the array with N*2. So adding N+1 when defining the extent might solve that. `ext = [0,inp.max(), N+1-0.5+(sp+0.5)/2., -(sp+0.5)/2.]`. Your `imshow` approach will probably be a lot faster when the number of bars is very high, its basically rasterizing upfront. Instead of pushing all the vectors to the mpl-backend and ending up with a rasterized image anyway.

Comment: @Rutger No, the ticklabels are also off by one bar in your case, and you don't make any space to both sides of the bars. Also when zooming in my example, the ticks are correct. The problem only seems to appear in the original size image. Could be some rounding issue?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to generate an image with the bars as pixels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dpi = 100
N = 100 # numbner of bars (approx. half the number of pixels)
w = 200 #width of plot in pixels
sp = 3  # spacing within axes in pixels
bp = 50; lp = 70 # bottom, left pixel spacing
bottom=float(bp)/(2*N+2*sp+2*bp)
top = 1.-bottom
left=float(lp)/(w+2*lp)
right=1.-left
figheight = (2*N+2*sp)/float(dpi)/(1-(1-top)-bottom) #inch
figwidth = w/float(dpi)/(1-(1-right)-left)

# this is the input array to plot
inp = np.random.rand(N)+0.16

ar = np.zeros((2*N+2*sp,w))
ninp = np.round(inp/float(inp.max())*w).astype(np.int)
for n in range(N):
    ar[2*n+sp, 0: ninp[n]] = np.ones(ninp[n])

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(figwidth, figheight), dpi=dpi)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=left, bottom=bottom, right=right, top=top)
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=0.5)

ext = [0,inp.max(), N-0.5+(sp+0.5)/2., -(sp+0.5)/2.]
ax.imshow(ar, extent=ext, interpolation="none", cmap="gray_r", origin="upper", aspect="auto")
ax.set_xlim((0,inp.max()*1.1))

ax.set_ylabel("item")
ax.set_xlabel("length")
plt.savefig(__file__+".png", dpi=dpi)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This will work for any setting of `dpi`.
Note that the ticklabels might appear a bit off, which is an inaccuracy from matplotlib; which I don't know how to overcome.

Comment: Many thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! I'll give both solutions a try..